# How to redirect output to ssh and stdout

Tags: bash

How to redirect echo to stdout and ssh?
So something like this:

`echo "Hello" | ssh ...@... "cat >> Log/my.log"`

I want to see both Hello on the screen as well as in the ssh output.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility might be

```
echo "Hello" | ssh user@host "tee -a Log/my.log"
```

Note that the text you see in the terminal is sent from remote host via `ssh`; it doesn't directly come from `echo`.